# Windows Store WinJS App and LESS

Tags: windows-store-apps, less, winjs

Is it possible to use LESS files in a WinJS application for the Windows Store?

I like how the Web Essentials extension works with web apps and would like to have this functionality in my WinJS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you've got it setup to compile and you add the output CSS files to your project, it works fine. I'm using it in a WinJS project.

Comment: I also figured out that if I install the Web Essentials, I can create a file with the .less extension and it will open the Web Essentials LESS compiler and covert any changes I make into a corresponding CSS file and a minified CSS file.

Comment: Yep, that's all it takes. It's pretty sweet and simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, the LESS Item Type does not seem to show up in a WinJS project.  So I had to create a CSS file and rename it to a .LESS file.